# How to add a LineBreak (\n) to a String.format with fixed String as format?

Tags: java, string

In the code below, message is a final String that have a `\n` inside it, and it doesn't work.

```
message = format = "Blah %d Blah Blah \nBlah Blah %s Blah"
interventionSize = number
UserID = String
String.format(Dic.message,interventionSize,userID)
```

How can I make the line break in this case, cannot find an answer.

BTW, I cannot use any kind of framework or external jar to do that (old code) have to use Plain Old Java.

Comment: What means *does not work*? Do you get an error-message? What is your output?

Comment: Indeed your are right... The problem is that the line doesn't break, I just get a huge Line instead of 2.

Comment: My guess: your're outputting the string to HTML. HTML doesn't care about `\n`, it only cares about `<BR>`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Having `\n` in a format string is just fine.

Perhaps you should try a platform specific new-line. With format strings you can use `%n`.

That is, try the following:

```
String.format(Dic.message.replace("\\n", "%n"), interventionSize, userId);
```

Comment: This one worked fine ! Thank you. will mark you as best answer as soon as it's possible !

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could use `System.lineSeparator()`. This will ensure platform independence. If you use a JDK before 1.7 its `System.getProperty("line.separator");`.

Code would then look like this:

```
String.format(Dic.message.replace("\\n", System.lineSeparator()), interventionSize, userId);
```

or this (for JDK before 1.7):

```
String.format(Dic.message.replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator")), interventionSize, userId);
```